# Solve the nonlinear first order PDE $u_xu_y-u_z^2=cu$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Suppose that $u$ is a function of $(x,y,z)$, then how to solve the equation

$$u_xu_y-u_z^2=cu,$$
where $c$ is a constant.

I want to get the general solutions. But this equation is nonlinear, I don't know how to use the characteristic method.

Comment: Try separation of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_xu_y-u_z^2=cu$$
Change of function: $\quad u=\frac{c}{4}v^2$
$$\left(\frac{c}{2}vv_x\right)\left(\frac{c}{2}vv_y\right)-\left(\frac{c}{2}vv_z\right)^2=c\left(\frac{c}{4}v^2\right)$$
$$v_xv_y-v_z^2=1$$
Try separation of variables : $\quad v=f(x)+g(y)+h(z)$
$$f'(x)g'(y)-\left(h'(z)\right)^2=1$$
This is possible only if $\begin{cases}
f'(x)=\alpha=\text{constant}\\
g'(y)=\beta=\text{constant}\\
h'(x)=\gamma=\text{constant}\\
\alpha\beta-\gamma^2=1
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
f(x)=\alpha\:x+c_1\\
g(y)=\beta\:y+c_2\\
h(x)=\gamma\:z+c_3\\
\alpha\beta-\gamma^2=1
\end{cases}$

$$v(x,y,z)=\alpha\:x+\beta\:y+\gamma\:z+\delta$$

$$\boxed{u(x,y,z)=\frac{c}{4}\left(\alpha\:x+\beta\:y+\gamma\:z+\delta\right)^2}$$
$$\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta =\text{constants, with condition }\quad\alpha\beta-\gamma^2=1$$